# Compare two excel files using python

Tags: python

I have two xlsx files as follows:

```
value1        value2   
3900162750    10    
3900163003    19
2311009200    22 

value1        value2   
3900163003    5    
3900162750    9
2311009200    88
```

How do I match `value1` from `xlsx1` with `xlsx2` and compare related `value2`?

for instance, match `3900163003` from `xlsx1` with `xlsx2` and find out `value2` is decreasing.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Easy. Use `pandas`. Find out how to find rows with a specific value. Compare the other value. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pandas`. First read the excel files as `pandas.DataFrame` objects. Then using `pd.DataFrame.merge` method, merge the two dataframes on `'value1'` column. Then create another column `'Decreasing'` by comparing the two `'value2'` columns. By default, the column from the left (in this case, `df1`) gets suffix `_x` and the one from the right (in this case, `df2`) gets suffix `_y`:

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.read_excel('first_excel_file.xlsx')
df2 = pd.read_excel('second_excel_file.xlsx')
df = df1.merge(df2, on='value1')
df['Decreasing'] = df['value2_x'] > df['value2_y']
```

Output:

```
       value1  value2_x  value2_y  Decreasing
0  3900162750        10         9        True
1  3900163003        19         5        True
2  2311009200        22        88       False
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `pandas` and pandas `merge` :

```
import pandas as pd

df = df1.merge(df2, on='value1', how= 'outer', suffixes=('_df1', '_df2'))
df['decrease'] = df['value2_df2'] < df['value2_df1']
```

giving:

```
       value1  value2_df1  value2_df2  decrease
0  3900162750          10           9      True
1  3900163003          19           5      True
2  2311009200          22          88     False
```

**Notes:**

- `how` parameter used to provide some output if `df1` and `df2` are not perfectly matching
- `suffixes` parameter used to provide the origin of the data
- it could be suitable to give a other name to the `'decrease'` column to remember the way it is computed

**Data**
from :

```
data1 = """
value1        value2   
3900162750    10    
3900163003    19
2311009200    22 
"""
data2 = """
value1        value2   
3900163003    5    
3900162750    9
2311009200    88
"""
df1 = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data1), sep=r' +')
df2 = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data2), sep=r' +')
```

In real live `read_csv` should be replaced by `read_excel`